# How do I match and sort rows in file2 to file1 preferably in R

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have two files. Each file contains a certain # of rows and columns. The second column in each file contains a unique GENE ID that are identical in both files (they are just in different rows). So for example

File 1 could have the gene "LINC00273" in row 3 (in the second column) and File 2 could have "LINC00273" in row 4002 (in the second column).

What I want to do is I want to sort File 2 so that if the first GENE in row 1 of File 1 is "VAGAB" then the first GENE of row 1 of File 2 is "VAGAB" with its entire row intact (the row has coverage information so I need the numbers to be moved accordingly).

Example: File 1 [#] corresponds to the row number

```
[1] GENE100X VAGAB VAGAB 1.0 1.0 1.0 5.0 11198.0 
...
[5000] GENE900X ZZZZ ZZZZ 1.0 0 4.2 1.0 78.0
```

File 2

```
[1] GENE44X AAAA AAAA 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
...
[5000] GENE106X VAGAB VAGAB 5.0 5.0 5.0 1.0 55.0
```

The expected output for file 2 would be:

```
[1] GENE106X VAGAB VAGAB 5.0 5.0 5.0 1.0 55.0
...
[5000] GENE300X ZZZZ ZZZZ 88.0 88.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
```

All files are tab delimited. All the numbers in examples (row numbers and column numbers) are made up. The only column that never changes is columns 2 and 3 these are the identical ones in both files so I want to sort using these.

I dont want to create a third file if it can be helped. I simply want the rows in file 2 to be identical to the rows in file 1 and the way to do this is to match them by their "Gene" name found in column 2 of both files.

R solutions preferred as that is what i'm currently learning, but I will take ANY solutions in any language and then I can use that as a template to come up with my own R solution as practice later.

Comment: Isn't this just a `merge`?

Comment: I am not looking to create a third file, I am simply trying to re-sort the second file I already have. I am not 100% familiar with the merge function, simply what I have read from the help page right now.

Comment: I attempted this but no merge doesn't do what I would like it to.

Comment: `merge(file2, file1["col2"], by="col2")`

Comment: It gives me the file2 back in alphabetical order which isn't what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's set up some example data first:

```
file1 <- data.frame(id=1:3,name=letters[c(3,1,2)])
#  id name
#1  1    c
#2  2    a
#3  3    b

file2 <- file1[c(2,3,1),]
file2$id <- paste("two",file2$id,sep="")
#    id name
#2 two2    a
#3 two3    b
#1 two1    c
```

Then match the rows using, well `match`:

```
file2[match(file1$name,file2$name),]
#    id name
#1 two1    c
#2 two2    a
#3 two3    b
```

Which is essentially the same as merging all the `file2` data against the matching rows of the `file1` data.

```
merge(file1["name"], file2, by="name", sort=FALSE)
#  name   id
#1    c two1
#2    a two2
#3    b two3
```

Comment: I guess I was using the merge function incorrectly, I should have spent more time reading the documentation. This seemed to have worked just by looking at the first few lines of data. If I want to write out this data to a file, would I simply use a write.table command?

Comment: @System - there is some nuance to it - the `sort=FALSE` is a bit funny for certain cases so `match` might be ideal for you. You can write it out if you like using `write.table/csv` yep.

Comment: Everything looks good so far. Some of the column ID's got reordered but that's nothing that a quick awk fix can't take care of. I've accepted this as the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Load both files into data frames (sample data used below).

```
file1 <- data.frame(id=1:3,name=letters[c(3,1,2)])
file2 <- file1[c(2,3,1),]
```

Then you can define a sort sequence with factors:

```
file1$name <- factor(file1$name, levels = file1$name)
file2$name <- factor(file2$name, levels = file1$name)
```

Then sort file2:

```
file2 <- file2[with(file2, order(name)) , ]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to retain all the information in the other columns. Is this expected?

Comment: So I re-tried this and I managed to retain all the info. But it isn't sorted correctly. It seems to sort based on A -> Z column 2 names instead of sorting them to the names in File 1

Comment: OK, I've edited it above and it works now. Is that what you are after?

Comment: This seems to work as well. Let me test it on some of my real data instead my test data and i'll let you know!